# Using JAXopt on constrained optimization(non-negative)

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, mathematical-optimization, jax

I am trying to do an optimization(using JAX) on my loss function, which comes from a basic physics model, which is two layers growing at different rates. Since the growing rates are always positive. I want to apply non-negative constrain on my optimizer. I looked up and found some documents on JAXopt. However, I am not very certain how to include it in my case since my loss function is defined pretty differently from their example.

Here is the short code (65 lines) that captures all the features that I want to show. I want to make sure that the params {raw_vs1, raw_vs2} are all non-negative using the projected gradient from JAXopt.

```
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import random, lax, grad, jit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import optax
from jaxopt import ProjectedGradient
from jaxopt.projection import projection_non_negative


# Optimization code setup
Nx = 1000
Nt = 100
key = random.PRNGKey(0)
dt = 0.01
reg_a = 1.0
reg_b = 1.0
reg_c = 1.0
d = 3
ds = 0.003

xs = jnp.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, Nx)
params = {
    'raw_vs1': random.uniform(key, shape=(Nt, Nx)),
    'raw_vs2': random.uniform(key, shape=(Nt, Nx))
}
target = jnp.power(xs, 4)
y0 = jnp.power(xs, 2)
lengths0 = jnp.power(xs, 0) * 0.001  # Initialize lengths as 0.1 for each point at each time step

def simulation(params, dt):
    vs1 = params['raw_vs1']
    vs2 = params['raw_vs2']
    vs = vs1 - vs2
    vf = (vs1 + vs2 )/ 2

    def _step(carry, t):
        y, lengths = carry
        y_new = y + vs[t] * dt
        lengths_new = lengths + vf[t] * dt  # Update lengths for each index at time step t
        return (y_new, lengths_new), (y_new, lengths_new)

    carry = (y0, lengths0)  # Initial carry with first time step lengths
    (yf,_), (ys, lengths_final) = lax.scan(_step, carry, jnp.arange(Nt))
    print("Shape of lengths_final:", lengths_final.shape)
    print("Shape of yf:", yf.shape)
    print("Shape of ys:", ys.shape)
    return yf, ys, lengths_final

def loss(params, dt, reg_a=reg_a, reg_b=reg_b, reg_c=reg_c, target_length=d):
    yf, ys, leng = simulation(params, dt)
    dt_term = jnp.sum(jnp.power(jnp.diff(ys, axis=0), 2))
    dx_term = jnp.sum(jnp.power(jnp.diff(ys, axis=1), 2))
    target_term = jnp.power(yf - target, 2)
    total_length = jnp.sum(leng[-1])
    length_term = (total_length - target_length) ** 2
    return reg_a*dt_term + reg_b*dx_term + jnp.sum(reg_c*target_term) + reg_c*length_term


# Optimization setup
g_loss = jit(grad(loss))
optimizer = optax.adam(0.01)
opt_state = optimizer.init(params)

# Optimization loop
loss_t = []
for i in range(2000):
    grads = g_loss(params, dt)
    updates, opt_state = optimizer.update(grads, opt_state)
    params = optax.apply_updates(params, updates)
    loss_t.append(loss(params, dt))
```

Comment: A very common solution to constrain parameter to being nom-negative is to use the log of the parameter instead. In many cases this also speeds up convergence. I'm sure it is worth a try.